# Can anyone tell me what this component is (goes to an AC motor)?

Tags: capacitor, identification

[image: photo of component]

[image: photo of component]

Does anyone know what this is? What do I replace it with?

This is from an old Wolf belt sander 5573 (which became the Makita 9401 I think) which was running, then just stopped. I checked the AC motor out (I think it's a universal motor) and it seemed OK.  This thing was pretty bulged and smelled when I tried it again.  It has the live and neutral as input directly from the switch and outputs three wires to the motor (the middle earth wire goes to the body of the stator).

Many thanks.

Comment: It's a capacitor of some sort, I think.

Comment: From the values (in \$\mu\$F) and diagram, it's a capacitor.  If it's the problem its a run capacitor and your motor is an induction motor.  For a belt sander, it's likely it's an induction motor.

Comment: This needs to be moved to a repair group, but I don't know which one to suggest...

Comment: Sparky has it- It's three capacitors, not one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is 3 capacitors used as noise/EMI filters, with one across the hot wire and neutral with an 'x' rating and a value of 100nF. Then 2 more capacitors with a value of 2.5nF with a 'y' rating from hot and neutral to Earth ground. They are rated for 250 VAC. The roll-off frequency is given as 1.6MHZ.

The 40174 S? maybe the part number. The last numbers are the date code.

**NOTE**: You need just 1 of 100nF 'x' rated tied from hot to neutral. The 2 2.5nF 'y' rated caps tie to Earth ground, then one spare lead goes to the 'hot' wire, often black in color, the other spare lead goes to neutral, often white. Earth ground is green or green with yellow stripe. These capacitors have no polarity, as they are rated for AC voltage. To be legit you should buy capacitors with the 'X' and 'Y' ratings, they are important.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvCTWQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Sparky, that's very informative. Is this a start capacitor or run capacitor or both? I'm wondering if it's strictly necessary or can I just wire the switch directly to the motor?  I am at a loss to know how to get a replacement at this point.  Is there a modern alternative I could replace it with do you think? Thanks for the help.

Comment: This cluster of capacitors are for noise filtering only. Start/Run capacitors have 100 times the value of the 'x' capacitor. You could buy them individually and wrap them in electrical tape. Not rated for damp weather unless you seal it all in a rubber epoxy.

Comment: So I'd need 3 x 100nF capacitors and 2 x 2.5nF capacitors? I'm a little confused as to how they'd be wired up.

Comment: I added some details to my answer.

Comment: Ok I think I've got you.  Can you have a look at this diagram I drew for you? https://i.imgur.com/NBnnRpm.gif

Comment: Your drawing is correct. It matches the one I just posted.

Comment: You beat me to it! One last thing - can I temporarily wire the motor directly to the switch without any capacitors to see if it runs ok? Really many thanks for your efforts in helping me!

Comment: Yes you can do that. Motor noise is ambiguous until it is measured using expensive equipment.